# Print out only odd elements from an IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I am having problems with an array where I for example want to printout the odd numbers in the list.

```
int[] numbers = new int[]{ 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };
Console.WriteLine(numbers.Where(n => n % 2 == 1).ToArray());
```

The ToString method does not seem to work? I do not want to loop through the elements. What can I do?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481964/how-to-convert-ienumerablestring-to-one-comma-separated-string

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to call `String.Join` to create a string with the contents of the sequence.

For example:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", numbers.Where(n => n % 2 == 1));
```

This uses the [new overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) which takes an `IEnumerable<T>`.
In .Net 3.5, you'll need to use the older version, which only takes a `string[]`:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(
    ", ", 
    numbers.Where(n => n % 2 == 1)
           .Select(n => n.ToString())
           .ToArray()
    )
);
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the other answers which point out that you can't just print out an array, I note that this doesn't print out all the odd numbers in the list because your test for oddness is incorrect.  Do you see why?

Hint: try testing it with negative numbers. Did you get the expected result? Why not?

Comment: because  5 % 2  is 1 and -5 % 2 is -1 ?

Comment: @lukas: You got it. The correct test for oddness is "x % 2 != 0".

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ForEach()`:

```
 numbers.ToList().ForEach(

    x=> 
  {if(x % 2 == 1)
      Console.WriteLine(x);
  });
```

Comment: Probably no reason to convert it to a List.. Just use foreach (not the extension) off of the enumerable.

Comment: He's refering to `foreach` blocks like `foreach (var x in numbers) { ... }`