# How to convert IEnumerable<string> to one comma separated string?

Tags: c#, string, linq, collections, ienumerable

Say that for debugging purposes, I want to quickly get the contents of an IEnumerable into one-line string with each string item comma-separated. I can do it in a helper method with a foreach loop, but that's neither fun nor brief. Can Linq be used? Some other short-ish way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IEnumerable to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414263/ienumerable-to-string)

Answer (score 166, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class C
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var a = new []{
            "First", "Second", "Third"
        };

        System.Console.Write(string.Join(",", a));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 60):

```
string output = String.Join(",", yourEnumerable);
```

[String.Join Method (String, IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx)

> Concatenates the members of a constructed IEnumerable collection of
>   type String, using the specified separator between each member.

Answer (score 13):

```
collection.Aggregate("", (str, obj) => str + obj.ToString() + ",");
```

Comment: This will add a superfluous comma at the end, but you could add `.TrimEnd(',')` to get rid of it.

Comment: Do this and you won't need to trim at the end
`collection.Aggregate((str, obj) => str + "," + obj.ToString());`

Comment: Note this is a potential performance issue. The Enumerable.Aggregate method uses the plus symbol to concatenate strings. It is much slower than the String.Join method.

Comment: string.join is cheaper and less code as chviLadislav mentioned

Answer (score 7):

**(a) Set up the IEnumerable:**

```
// In this case we are using a list. You can also use an array etc..
List<string> items = new List<string>() { "WA01", "WA02", "WA03", "WA04", "WA01" };
```

**(b) Join the IEnumerable Together into a string:**

```
// Now let us join them all together:
string commaSeparatedString = String.Join(", ", items);

// This is the expected result: "WA01, WA02, WA03, WA04, WA01"
```

**(c) For Debugging Purposes:**

```
Console.WriteLine(commaSeparatedString);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
IEnumerable<string> foo = 
var result = string.Join( ",", foo );
```

Comment: The .ToArray() at the end of String.Join is needed for .NET < 4

Comment: no it isn't.  Why would you need to put .ToArray() on a string?  That will fail.

Answer (score 0):

To join a large array of strings into a string, do not directly use `+`, rather use a `StringBuilder` to iterate one by one, or `String.Join` in one shot.

Comment: OT: For concatenations of 3 operands the compiler will turn those operations to one call of the string.Append method taking 3 parameters. So with more than 3 operands, StringBuilder come in handy.

Comment: you should have provided a sample code