# Can C# print collection values as simple as Java does?

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections

In Java I can print values of collection just passing collection to output:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>(){
            {
                put(1, "one");
                put(2, "two");
            }
};
System.out.println(map);
```

Output:

```
{1=one, 2=two}
```

In C# similar code would give me info about collection types, instead of values inside, I've been looking for it, but as I understand in C# you have to work around to get output of values from collection.
As I understand with C# you can't show values of collection as simple as using Java, am I right ?

Comment: Existing suggestion (not making Java comparison so) - Dictionary/HashSet - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899171/is-there-anyway-to-handy-convert-a-dictionary-to-string/17281317, any type of collection for any element type - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079867/c-sharp-ienumerable-print-out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When passing an object of any type to - say - `Console.WriteLine()`, the `ToString()` method of that object is called to convert it to a printable string.

The default implementation of `ToString()` returns the type name. Some collections have overridden implementations of `ToString()` that return a string containing information like the number of elements in the collection.

But by default there is no such functionality as in your java example.

A simple way to get such an output would be to use `string.Join` and some LINQ:

```
Console.WriteLine("{" + string.Join(", ", map.Select(m => $"{m.Key}={m.Value}")) + "}");
```

If the elements in your collection already have a proper `.ToString()` implementation (like e.g. `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` as Michael LY pointed out), you can skip the `Select` part:

```
Console.WriteLine("{" + string.Join(", ", map) + "}");
```

Comment: I find this answer more elegant : 
var asString = string.Join(";", dictionary);

http://stackoverflow.com/a/17281317/4083283

Comment: @MickaelLY a thx, so the `.ToString()` of a `KeyValuePair<,>` obviously is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you'd have to join stated from the previous example.
Or simply use a loop formatted nicely to display the elements in the collection.
Example:

in Java using .ToString() would print out the whole Collection

```
int [] array1 = new int{10, 20, 30};
```

you would get [10, 20, 30] in the output.

in C#:

```
int [] array1 = [10, 20, 30]
```

you would get System.Int32[]... in the output

So it's best to use a for loop for c#

```
for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(array1[i]);
}
```

//remember that Console.WriteLine() automatically calls .ToString()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).